# Handling radiobuttons in popup dialog using webdriver

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, popup

For a web based dialog popup in an angular JS app, it has 2 radio buttons whose xpaths are as follow :-
1. `html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/wizardviews/div[2]/div[1]/label/input`
2. `html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/wizardviews/div[2]/div[2]/label/input1`

The code is able to open the popup but not able to click on the radio button as the click enables the "Next" button on the same dialog.

Below is the HTML code for more clarification :-

```
<html class="js flexbox flexboxlegacy canvas canvastext webgl no-touch geolocation postmessage no-websqldatabase indexeddb hashchange history draganddrop websockets rgba hsla multiplebgs backgroundsize borderimage borderradius boxshadow textshadow opacity cssanimations csscolumns cssgradients no-cssreflections csstransforms csstransforms3d csstransitions fontface generatedcontent video audio localstorage sessionstorage webworkers applicationcache svg inlinesvg smil svgclippaths ng-scope" ng-app="AtlasEMPI" style="">
<head>
<body class="ng-scope modal-open" ng-controller="AtlasEMPICtrl">
<div class="container body-content divEMPIContainer">
<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>
<span class="select2-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite"></span>
<div class="row">
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" ng-style="{'z-index': 1040 + (index && 1 || 0) + index*10}" ng-class="{in: animate}" modal-backdrop="" style="z-index: 1040;"></div>
<div class="modal fade ng-isolate-scope dialogClass in" ng-click="close($event)" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}" ng-class="{in: animate}" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" modal-window="" window-class="dialogClass" size="lg" index="0" animate="animate" style="z-index: 1050; display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" ng-class="{'modal-sm': size == 'sm', 'modal-lg': size == 'lg'}" style="">
<div class="modal-content" ng-transclude="">
<div class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" empiwizarddialog="" wizardoptions="empiwizardOption">
<div class="row">
<div class="empimodal-content" ng-class="(empiwizardOption.calledsource == 'usermgmt')?'empimodal-user':''">
<span class="adcfonticon-cancelcircle close-btn" ng-click="empiwizardOption.cancel(step)"></span>
<div class="empipanel" ng-class="(empiwizardOption.header ==false)?'empipanelnoborder' : 'empipanel'">
<div class="adcmodal-header" ng-show="empiwizardOption.header">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div style="padding-top:15px">
<div class="slide-frame ng-scope" ng-switch="getCurrentStep()">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-switch-when="confirmReject">
<wizardviews viewname="confirmReject">
<div class="row">
<hr class="empihorizontalruler empihorizontalrulertop">
<div class="row input-group createnewMPIDdidlaog">
<div class="col-sm-6">
<label class="lblradiorejectdialog">
<input class="rdoreject ng-pristine ng-valid" type="radio" value="createnewMPID" ng-model="radioreject" style="" name="1NM">
```

Comment: I don't see any question in your _question_... what is the problem?

Comment: Question is the code is unable to find or click on the radio button as mentioned above "The code is able to open the popup but not able to click on the radio button as the click enables the "Next" button on the same dialog."

Comment: Any updates from anyone??

Comment: Come on, the xpaths are really scary (don't you have any id or class or name that would identify the elements?) where's the code that cannot open something? You don't expect us to follow the xpaths to identify which elements you mean? Your code is poorly formateted (horizontal scrolling) and I bet you have some javascript codebehind for this that might be interesting.

Comment: Apart from xpaths we don't have anything which we can use for locating the item. The code which is available with me ,I have already shared above. Let me know if you have any other inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written earlier ,the xpath for a radio button on a popup dialog is "html/body/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/wizardviews/div[2]/div[1]/label/input" but the code was unable to find the element.
The HTML code was:-"input type="radio" value="createnewMPID" ng-model="radioreject" class="rdoreject ng-pristine ng-valid" name="7MB" "

So now I used the locator as Xpath = "//input[@value='createnewMPID'

It's working fine and script is unable to locate the element and click as well.